# "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty", but they aren't (to my knowledge) nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a bootstrap modal form using Rails, however I keep getting the aforementioned error. Here is my form code (results in error):

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@restaurant, @review], url: 
new_restaurant_review_path([@restaurant, @review])) do |f| %>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
before_action :set_restaurant
def new
  @review = Review.new(restaurant: @restaurant)
end
private
def set_restaurant
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
end
```

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You shouldn't be submitting a form to the new path (usually a create path) and so it may be rendering the 'new' action and thus not reinstantiating the restaurant or review variable.

Comment: Please update your controller's code so we can see how you get @restaurant

Comment: Ok, I updated my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Are you actually receiving :restaurant_id in the params for the `new` action? In the other words, have you checked that the restaurant is being loaded properly? Also, you don't need that before_action, but we can't about that later.

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo yes, because `find` generate an exception if can't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the form is for a new `review` that belongs to a `restaurant`. I know in older versions of Rails, something like this would work.

`<%= form_for([@restaurant, Review.new]) do |f| %>`

Comment: No problem @ZakSingh

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your @restaurant variable and make sure it's not nil.  I can see that you are initializing @review, but unless you've initialized @restaurant with a before_action or something like that, it's not being initialized in your new action.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch that I omitted that. I updated my post to make that more obvious what I'm doing.